# Accelerometer data

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am tring to build an app that will log accelerometer data from this link :
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-barometer-logger-acquiring-sensor-data/

Thing is that I am getting some error and don't understand why am I getting these errors. 
I am pasting my code below:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;



import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    SensorManager sensorManager = null;
    Sensor sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    SensorEventListener myListenerInstance = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sensorManager.registerListener(myListenerInstance, sensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        long timestamp = event.timestamp;
        float value = event.values[0];

        // String res=String.valueOf(event.values[0])+"#"+String.valueOf(event.values[1])+"#"+String.valueOf(event.values[2]);

        // Log.d("test", res);
    }

    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(myListenerInstance, sensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
    protected void onStop(){

        sensorManager.unregisterListener(myListenerInstance);
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

The error that I am getting is here:

```
06-22 21:44:27.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9918): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-22 21:44:27.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9918): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.rasam.sampleproject/com.rasam.sampleproject.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 21:44:27.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9918):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
06-22 21:44:27.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9918):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
06-22 21:44:27.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9918):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java)
06-22 21:44:27.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9918):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
06-22 21:44:27.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9918):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
06-22 21:44:27.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9918):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
06-22 21:44:27.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9918):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
06-22 21:44:27.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9918):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 21:44:27.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9918):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
06-22 21:44:27.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9918):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
06-22 21:44:27.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9918):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
06-22 21:44:27.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9918):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-22 21:44:27.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9918): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 21:44:27.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9918):     at com.rasam.sampleproject.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:26)
06-22 21:44:27.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9918):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-22 21:44:27.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9918):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java)
06-22 21:44:27.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9918):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java)
06-22 21:44:27.322: E/AndroidRuntime(9918):     ... 12 more
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening???

Answer (score 0):

```
SensorManager sensorManager = null;
Sensor sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
```

Immediately after you initialize sensorManager to null, you try to call one of its methods, something which can only result in a null pointer exception.

You must be sure that this later line of code which initializes your sensorManager is always executed before you try to use the sensorManager:

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

Likely you should be initializing sensor to null as well at the top of your class, and then getting yourself a real sensorManager, and subsequently a real sensor only in your onCreate() method.

```
SensorManager sensorManager = null;
Sensor sensor = null;
SensorEventListener myListenerInstance = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: CHanged it but this seems not the problem at all

Comment: You have a null pointer exception on line 26. That's impossible from the code you posted, so the lines have obviously been shifted in position. However, the issue raised in this answer will be an unavoidable error of the same type as the error message you posted, falling at nearly the same line.